# What is the attack complexity if two stream ciphers are connected in cascade?

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher

What is the attack complexity when Grain-128 and Trivium are cascaded? Is it 2^(256 + 128) since internal state of Grain is 256 bits and assuming that  IV is unknown before encryption?

Comment: That will depend on how keys for Grain-128 and Trivium are obtained. If that's from hashing a password.. Also, the internal 256-bit state of Grain-128 can not make attack more costly than implied by the key size.